# How do I make 15 static PHP classes work together well?

Tags: php, singleton

I have a personal PHP application that has about 15 classes. Each class is only initiated once as a page is executed. In other words, when the page loads:

- 15 classes are loaded, and as each class file gets loaded, I create one instance of the class.
- The application (so far) is designed so every variable in the system has one state during the generation of a page. I use global vars to access each of these
- It's worked fine for 3 years, but I am the sole developer and a goo debugger of my own code.

I have heard all the issues with Singletons, and I hate  doing, "global $var" all over the place. Please tell me how to pull this type of structure out and into something developers would love. I want to write software the right way, but I can't seem to find a very simple code framework for this type of execution.

Oh - and I'm not looking for a MVC framework solution. I would love your thoughts on how I take 15 classes and turn them into a proper framework for working together. I would also love an articulation on how "stupid" it is to develop this way.

Comment: Sure, global variables are evil, but there is also the issue of over-engineering. That you have separated your code into classes  makes me think that things aren't that bad. If it's not broken..

Comment: One of those times I wish PHP could inherit from mutiple classes.

Comment: @MitMaro: Really? Most languages do not have multiple inheritance. By design.

Answer (score 2):

If you have variables you want all classes to have access to, maybe you could try inheritance, for example something like

```
class Settings
{
    var $page_name = "My Page";
    var $database_name = "my_db";
}
```

and then let all classes inherit this class like

```
class Page extends Settings
{
    var $id = 0;
    var $template = "";
    function __construct() {}
}

$page = new Page();
echo $page->page_name;
```

or you could define the values as constants, if that is what they are

```
define("PAGE_NAME", "My Page");
```

you would have access to PAGE_NAME everywhere

I'm not in any way saying this is the right way, it's just *a* way. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when I was developing php apps. What I ended up doing was creating classes of static methods and static variables. In essence they work somewhat like namespaces. I am not sure how "standard" this is but it works very well in practice.

The only other option would be to create a singleton like you mentioned in your question, but imho that can be overkill unless you need something like constructors and deconstructors.

Example:

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    private static $my_static_variable;

    static public function myStaticMethod(){
        return self::$my_static_variable;
    }
}
```

You can then use this anywhere without the need to use global:

```
function foo(){
    MyClass::myStaticMethod();
}

class Bar{
    public function myBarMethod(){
        MyClass::myStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been considering the same thing myself, and the only conclusion I could come to way to crack open an MVC framework and see how it's built.

The other thing is as mentioned, to start with a single super class and inherit down from there.

So have a class Object, then inherit that into something and so on and so on.